# Reference aspx pages from different web project

Tags: asp.net, multiple-projects

I have an ASP .NET web form solution with multiple web projects. There is one core web project and each of the other web project work as pluggable modules.

I have written a post build event to copy aspx/ascx files and *.dll of child web projects to the core web project directory.

The issue is - I am not able to call child project aspx pages from the core project. I get "Could not load type" error.

Is it possible to use aspx pages in different project if i refer that webproject dll and copy the aspx files to the main application? What am i doing wrong here. I would greatly appreciate any pointer in the right direction. Thank you.

Sanjay

Comment: Do they need to act as stand alone web apps themselves also or are they only ever going to be accessed from within the core project?   

One option would be to deploy them as virtual apps in the core projects website.  You will have problems with session management between the apps but you can get around this by doing the session management server side.

Comment: No they will not act as stand alone projects. They are just for logical separation so that different teams can work on different modules. All the modules will be access from core project. For this i copy aspx/ascx from these projects to core project at some designated locations. Also note that i have a master file in the core that is used by child projects. So i cannot create different virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to this. The key is to define you assemblies in the web.config file and then define a probing path. Following is the link with details-
http://weblogs.asp.net/chrismoseley/archive/2008/10/28/shared-assemblies-without-the-gac.aspx

Comment: Nothing about how to use ServerExecutor on that page.